# Reached Question Limit

Tags: support, user-accounts, banned

Can someone tell me why I've reached my question limit on the English Stackexchange site? All my questions are generally positive.

I suspect it's because I gave out a 50 rep bounty when I was low in rep and the system incorrectly detected that potential downvotes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although moderators are not privy to the algorithm behind this determination, it's unlikely to be reputation related. More likely by far is that of the 12 questions you've asked, only 3 remain open and not deleted.

Stack Exchange management have provided [a more detailed breakdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236568/153355) of contributing factors, including this part:

> Basically, the system trains on how we'll you've done *overall* (either your entire account history, or the last 45 days for newer accounts, dropping the most negatively scored), and how well you've done *recently* (the last 15 days). That gets us the following:
>
> - Number of questions asked in the last 45 days
> - Average score of your questions in that time
> - Number of questions asked in the last 15 days
> - Average score of your questions in that time
> - Average time elapsed between questions in the last 45 and 15 days

The only ways to improve this situation are to found in [these instructions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/153355).

Comment: Oh I see, it's because I deleted too many negatively scored questions. If so, what's the next step to regain my asking privileges?

Comment: @NoName You’ll have to follow [these instructions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/153355).

Comment: @NoName It’s not that you deleted them, per se, but that you have too many negatively scoring questions, deleted or otherwise. That they’re deleted makes it harder to get out of the ban, because if you undelete them and improve them, people might vote them up, which is what you need to please the Almighty Algorithm.

Comment: I agree with @DanBron on this. The recommended way to get out of this impasse is to improve downvoted questions wherever you can. Deleting them makes no difference since they are still downvoted. Note that you can edit questions before you undelete them.

Comment: Interesting, although I see a flaw in the algorithm if the questions are just plain irrelevent or bad (newbie mistakes). Then no amount of editing will save them considering we can't change the entire topic of the question, thus, stuck being restricted from questioning forever?  Would providing great answers to other people's questions help?

Comment: @NoName: Providing great answers will improve your rep and give your more privileges, but won't improve the average score of your questions: you may have to wait until the algorithm decides you have enough days per question (=few enough bad questions per day.)

Comment: I don't see how it's a "flaw" if the algorithm sees a bunch of 'newbie mistakes' and prevents you from posting a bunch more of the same.  Once you start posting non-newbie-mistake questions those will go into the algorithm as well and increase or eventually remove your limitation.