# Has the wait between asking two questions been removed?

Tags: discussion

Earlier, I had to wait for 40 minutes in between the posting of two consecutive questions. However, today I was able to ask questions without having to wait.

Have the rules changed? or It's because of my reputation increase or something?

Comment: [Reached Question Limit](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11031/reached-question-limit) and [50 question per month limit?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4535/50-question-per-month-limit)

Comment: I'm also confused, as far as I can tell from your profile, today you have asked only one question, not two. Did you delete your second question?  https://english.stackexchange.com/users/269543/rohit-shekhawat?tab=questions

Comment: @Mari-LouA Actually I asked the other question on the literature website. However, I also posted 2 questions on this website as well, and I deleted 1 :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, for users above a certain rep amount, this restriction is removed. The magic number is actually 125:

> - Users with < 125 rep [must wait] [40 minutes since their last question anywhere on the network](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265) (This applies to the user's IP address, not their account. If the user shares that IP with other users, they can be limited by the other user asking a question anywhere on the network.)
>
> [image]

Note that you will [still be rate limited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281959/323179) on other sites where you have <125 rep.

Comment: _prepares to ask __all__ the questions_

Comment: Oh! I actually did check some of the more ambiguous privileges to see what was in there but I guess I didn't look hard enough! XD How does this work anyway? [Our privileges list only mentions voting against answers at 125 rep.](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)

Comment: @Mitch YEAHHHHHHHH

Comment: @Tonepoet Yes, they should tell about this privilege (125 rep) on that list as well.

Answer (score -2):

Nothing seems to be wrong or altered here. It is probably because your reputation increased. [At 9 or fewer reputation points,](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) you are considered a "new user", and your ability to participate is severely hampered, probably as a safeguard against spam.  This includes an inability to "ask or answer questions too rapidly". That restriction is allegedly removed once you have 10 or more points, alongside the inability to post more than 8 hyperlinks, and answer protected questions.

Granted, at 150 rep. it seems to me that you should have noticed a change much earlier, perhaps when you were presumably notified of the privilege in your inbox, but the privilege is vaguely named because it bestows a few benefits, and I am assuming you did not notice sooner because you simply did not bother to try again until now, under the assumption it would not work.

Comment: Yup! You are 100% right when you said  "I am assuming you did not notice sooner because you simply did not bother to try again until now, under the assumption it would not work" I really thought so XD

Comment: *[...] your ability to participate is **severely hampered** [...] That restriction is **allegedly** removed [...]* is not exactly the right way to explain the fact, and kind of implies SE is discriminating new users intentionally. Also, as Laurel said, the limit is much higher, at 125 rep.

Comment: @ConstantErik 1. Yes, well, that's what I think.  [Discrimination](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/discrimination) is inherent to any system of [privilege](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/privilege), and S.E. is discriminating against new users intentionally.  Otherwise everyone would have complete access to the whole feature set without needing to earn it. Perhaps Stack Exchange is exercising its better discrimination, but that does not make it nondiscriminatory.  2. This answer is wrong on that point, but I decided to leave it up due to anomalies in the help center.